# Parameterizing Azure launch of scale set per machine with template

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines

We need to run load testing on a server consumed by Windows clients. For this, we want to spin up around 1000 Windows VMs and run a script in each, with different parameters for each of them, along with an executable.

I've been tinkering with Azure and PowerShell for a couple of days. From what I've read and investigated, a scale set might be our best bet for this instance.

The only obstacle for this (besides some limitations with large scale sets and load balancing) is that I've found no way to specify some required parameters to each VM when using a template to launch the scale set. Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

It would also seem that Desired State Configuration would be a viable aid on this, but it presents the same problem.

Comment: You can use the samples mentioned in this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-template-windows

Q. How many VMs can I have in a scale set?
A. A scale set can have 0 to 1,000 VMs based on platform images, or 0 to 300 VMs based on custom images.

Answer (score 0):

I currently did something similar where I created a Load and performance testing environment using [ARM Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates). The best way to do this is by using a [copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) loop in the ARM template and deploying all the VMs in parallel to save time.

Moreover, as the VMs are being used for load testing and you want to run custom configuration scripts, I strongly recommend to use [Azure DevTest Labs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devtest-lab/) where you can create formulas and artifacts for pre and post deployment.

Let me know if this helps.